# Creating Shortcut where folder name is having unicode characters

Tags: c#, wpf, shortcut, wsh, lnk

I have been using the below code to create shortcuts dynamically. But the targetPath throws Argument exception when the folder name has unicode characters like Thai,greek language.

```
IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell shell = new WshShell();
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);
shortcut.Description = "My shortcut description";   // The description of the shortcut
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = currentPath;


shortcut.TargetPath = targetFileLocation;                 // The path of the file that will launch when the shortcut is run
shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: You may need to create logic for replacement string (like u1234) for the unicode chars which cannot be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Shell32.dll from file system, go to COM tab of the "Add ref..." dialog and select the component named "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation"

```
string destPath = @"c:\temp";
string shortcutName = @"नमस्ते.lnk";

// Create empty .lnk file
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(destPath, shortcutName);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0]);
// Create a ShellLinkObject that references the .lnk file
Shell32.Shell shl = new Shell32.ShellClass();
Shell32.Folder dir = shl.NameSpace(destPath);
Shell32.FolderItem itm = dir.Items().Item(shortcutName);
Shell32.ShellLinkObject lnk = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)itm.GetLink;
// Set the .lnk file properties
lnk.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\notepad.exe";
lnk.Description = "nobugz was here";
lnk.Arguments = "sample.txt";
lnk.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
lnk.Save(path);
```

Comment: I am nobugz.  I was there.  Just don't pretend that this is your code, you must provide attribution.

Comment: This answer is an unattributed copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542488/7565574