# Create shortcut containing unicode path

Tags: powershell, unicode, symlink, shortcut

I'm trying to create shortcut in Windows 7, but after I try and a few google, turn out there is no way in PowerShell.

Question: Is there any other way to batch create shortcut that support unicode path and filename?

Tried using symbolic link, but it's not working (returns file not exist) when a unicode path.

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\f[o]o♭\pr[o]file♭.txt" -Value "C:\b[a]r♭\pr[o]file♭.txt"
```

Code I used, but didn't work when unicode path, filename.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($lnkpath)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $tarpath
$Shortcut.Save()
```

One of the google search:
[Create shortcut with Unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542005/create-shortcut-with-unicode-character)

---

Thank you for your prompt reply, then I tried.

```
$tarpath = "C:\f[o]o♭\pr[o]file♭.txt"
$lnkpath = "C:\b[a]r♭\pr[o]file♭.txt"

$tarpath = $tarpath.Replace('[','`[')
$tarpath = $tarpath.Replace(']','`]')
$lnkpath = $lnkpath.Replace('[','`[')
$lnkpath = $lnkpath.Replace(']','`]'

# echo print $tarpath like this -> C:\b`[a`]r♭\pr`[o`]file♭.txt,
# but I'm not sure when it is the same at -Path $tarpath

New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $tarpath -Value $lnkpath
```

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]`: ```-Path C:\f`[o`]o♭\pr`[o`]file♭.txt```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, then I tried.

$tarpath="C:\f[o]o♭\pr[o]file♭.txt"
$lnkpath="C:\b[a]r♭\pr[o]file♭.txt"

$tarpath=$tarpath.replace('[','`[')
$tarpath=$tarpath.replace(']','`]')
$lnkpath=$lnkpath.replace('[','`[')
$lnkpath=$lnkpath.replace(']','`]')

echo print like this -> ``C:\b`[a`]r♭\pr`[o`]file♭.txt``, but I'm not sure when it is the same at -Path $tarpath

New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $tarpath -Value $lnkpath

Comment: Backticks in comments are a nightmare, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43306251/edit) your question instead :-)

Comment: Only the `-Path` argument to `New-Item` needs to have them escaped, not the `-Value` argument

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen
thank you, it finally work, thank for your help. =]

Comment: You're welcome :-) Added a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see a `-Path` parameter on a builtin cmdlet, assume that it supports [wildcard globbing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088(v=vs.85).aspx).

This means that `[x]` is not interpreted literally, but as a simple character class substitute. In your example, that means `C:\f[o]o♭\pr[o]file♭.txt` is interpreted as `C:\foo♭\profile♭.txt` which is why it complains that the target path doesn't exist.

To get around this, escape the square brackets with a backtick (`` ` ``):

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path 'C:\f`[o`]o♭\pr`[o`]file♭.txt' -Value "C:\b[a]r♭\pr[o]file♭.txt"
```

Comment: This is not shortcut, but symbolic link.

Comment: @yukihane it is indeed a symlink. If you have a question about an actual .lnk with a unicode target path and can't find the answer posted on the site already, feel free to submit a new question