# how to get the target path of shortcut having unicode characters

Tags: c#, .net

i can easly get the target path of any shortcut file without unicode characters.But when theres a unicode character in shortcut filename, i get the target path as blank.

here is my code

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
IWshShortcut link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(path_lnk);
targetpath= link.TargetPath;
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542005/create-shortcut-with-unicode-character

Comment: its creating shortcut not getting target path of shortcut

Comment: I doubt it matters if you set or get the TargetPath property. The answer there states that WshShell is an outdated technology that just doesn't support Unicode.

Comment: then whats the best way of getting shortcut even with unicode?

Comment: Have you tried using the linked answer up until the `Shell32.ShellLinkObject lnk = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)itm.GetLink;` line and look what `lnk.Path` says?

Comment: Yes it worked thanks.